# Call waiting beeps

Tags: cyanogenmod, calls, htc-desire-s, call-waiting

My phone is the HTC Desire S.  I have call waiting enabled.  On the original HTC firmware I got bundled with the phone, this meant that when another call was coming through I heard a double-beep twice in the background, and then it stopped.  Now that I have installed CyanogenMod 7, I'm getting that double-beep continuing for the entire 20 seconds that the call is waiting, if I don't answer it.  How can I restore it so that I just get the double-beep twice and then it stops when a new call is coming through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, CM does not (yet) support to configure it. Issue [5268](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=5268) at the CM tracker addresses this (yours, i take it?) - so anybody else affected is encouraged to "star" it.

Meanwhile, an app named [Call Waiting Configurations](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidea.callwaiting) might provide a work-around (not sure, I didn't test it myself) until the CM team adds the possibility of configuration. Or you could instead activate the checkbox to "vibrate on call waiting":

[image: Vibrate on call waitng - CM]

Additionally, the following apps might be worth checking:

- [Advanced Call Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.advcallsettings)
- [Call Wait Vibrate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roy.cwn)

Comment: May I ask which detail solved the issue for you? Just being curious :)